# JSOUP Android issue

Tags: android, gradle, jsoup

**My question:**
Is it possible to set Android Studio indicate with yellow color in gradle file when new version of jsoup released? Like many of other dependencies.

Here is my repositories line:

```html
repositories
        {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
            google()
        }
```

**Reason:**
Today my app begins to crash on all installed devices while checking new version from Google Play, because jsoup version was old (1.10.3) and become incompatible. After updating to 1.11.2 error solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean like this?
[image]

Maybe this is not elegant way, but I produce it by create two gradle(module level) with one with deterministic depenedencies build and another one with wildcard build like this `compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:+`.

When there is ANR or CRASH report on console I will swap my gradle file to dynamic dependency to check for the update.